# how to store multiple dynamically generated textbox values into an array in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, dynamic, textbox

Pls help,

I have a form which dynamically generates  textboxes. For eg:

```
        on |button| click
           |textbox 1|
           |textbox 2|
           |textbox 3|
           |textbox 4|
           .
           .
           .
           |textbox n|

           |submit|
```

Where id of the textbox keeps autoincrementing while the name remains the same. 
What I require is when i submit the form the values of the textboxes generated must be stored in an array and then the array is stored in database. How to store dynamically generated textbox value into a single array using codeigniter? Im new to codeigniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View file

```
<?php
     for($i=1;$i<10;$i++) { ?>
         <textarea name="texta[<?php echo $i;?>]"></textarea>
     <?php } ?>
```

Controller that catches the form

```
$array_of_textboxes = $this->input->post('texta');
```

Then your textbox values are in the array

You can have an array without keys if your html is

```
<textarea name="texta[]"></textarea>
```

Comment: actually in view file i am creating textboxes via javascript. consider that 3 or 4 textboxes where created. What abt it then?

Comment: doesn't matter, if you use jQuery just `$('.mytextareas').attr('name', 'texta[' + myid + ']');`

Comment: sorry, the selector should, of course, point to your current textarea

Answer (score 0):

you should increment the name as well. Then your script which receives the POST generates an Array which looks like the Thing u want to have. Then u can use "serialzie($array)" to create a String version of the Array. This should be stroed in database. Then u can use "unserialze($string)" to get your array back.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ajaxSubmit plugin for jQuery: [Link](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/)
It sends all the form elements to the form's action url. The $_POST array structure is: array("element_name"=>element_data).
If you have multiple textboxes like you do, and if you name them as an array:
`<input type='text' name='textbox[]'>` the plugin will send them in an array for inside the post. the first textbox will be `$_POST['textbox'][0]`